# Inserting unicode into string with sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8, sqlalchemy, unicode-string

I am using sqlAlchemy to interact with a postgres database. It is all set to work with inserting string data. The data I receive is normally utf-8 and the setup works very well. As a edge case, recently, data came up in the format `somedata\xtrailingdata`.

SQLAlchemy is attempting to make this entry with `somedata` completely stripping out everything after `\x`.

Can you please tell me if there's a way to instruct SQLAlchemy to just attempt inserting the whole thing instead of removing the unicode part.

I have attempted 
`create_engine(dbUri, convert_unicode=True, client_encoding='utf8')`

`create_engine(dbUri, convert_unicode=False, client_encoding='utf8')`

`create_engine(dbUri, convert_unicode=False)`

None worked out so far. I really would appreciate your input in inserting this data into string column.

PS:Can't modify the column type of DB. This is a very edge case, not the norm.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing Unicode about it. `\x` is a byte literal prefix and requires a hex value to follow. PostgreSQL also supports the `\x` syntax also, so it may be PostgreSQL that's dropping it.

Consider escaping all slashes or find-replace on `\x` before handing to SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be `\x00`. When passed to SQLAlchemy an a value with `\x00`, it truncates it to the data preceding `\x00`. We traced the problem to the C library underneath the SQLAlchemy.